# Need good source control

Tags: version-control, ubuntu

I am working on my C programming skills.  I decided to run Ubunutu Linux and use code::blocks as my IDE.  Now, I need a good source control.

Something that's easy for a beginner to administer (I want to concentrate on coding not managing a server)
Free
Hopefully has a plugin that integrates well with code::blocks

I plan to use source control for my own use.  I want to be able to undo my changes if I make too many mistakes.  I also want to be able to revert back to an old version and do side-by-side comparisons.

Maybe one day, my buddy and I could work on some code together (from different locations), but this is not a major concern at this time.

What works for me?

Comment: The description matches about every remotely modern VCS, including SVN (the server management part *can* be tricky but you might as well copypaste the setup for an ultra-simple local server and use that one). It's basically an invitation for people to simply post their favourite VCS...

Comment: @delnan - If you feel the question is subjective you should vote to migrate to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.  Downvoting and closing the question discourages question answerers from asking questions.  I do not have enough knowledge of Source control in this context to determine subjectivity, thats why I asked.

Comment: @P.Brian: I did neither. But I'm not sure if programmers.SE can use this question either in its current shape - they already have http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/940/what-are-your-favorite-version-control-systems.

Comment: I didn't vote to migrate this to Programmers because I suspect it'll get closed as subjective and argumentative there as well. If you want to repost it, make sure you take a look at their [guidelines for good subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Delnan is right, the way this is worded just invites people to throw down strong-headed opinions about their *favorite* VCS, rather than provide constructive insight. It could be reworded, but closing heads off the problem before it happens.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I got what I needed out of this question.  Please delete.  Thanks

Comment: Don't remove the question just because *you* got what *you* needed—others upvoted both the question and the answers, which means they found them to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/). I personally prefer Mercurial.

Comment: The nice thing about DVCS for this situation is easy migration from solo -> team project.

Comment: @Brian.Mackey: Add Bazaar (developed by Canonical) to the list and you can make use of their online offering Launchpad.net as well. But my personal preference is Git.

Answer (score 2):

- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) is still very popular and stable.  It's centralized though, which these days is considered "the old way."  (I've heard people say "Git is to SVN what BitTorrent is to FTP.")
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/) is pretty much the in thing right now.  In my opinion it has a higher learning curve, but its adoption by the open-source community is [widespread](https://github.com/).
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) is a great DVCS and, in my opinion, doesn't get enough attention.  [Great commercial products](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) are built on top of it, though, so growing your project to a commercial system is pretty smooth.

[There are others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software).